# Calling a method upon exiting Geofence

Tags: android, location, android-geofence

I want to call a method in when the user has exited the geofence radius, I'm not entirely sure how to go about that. It seems I have to work with GeofenceTransitionsIntentService(), but all I'm finding is outdated code

Comment: How hard did you look? The API docs have a full fledged example on how to do this. Simply use a conditional to check `geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT` in the `onHandleIntent` of your Geofence Service: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: I'm stupid, and this was actually it. I wish I could mark it as the answer! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API docs have a full fledged example on how to do this. Simply use a conditional to check `geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT` in the onHandleIntent of your Geofence Service: [developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) –